Can I pass an @Environment property as a parameter to a subview in order to use two-way bindings on its properties?
I'd like to know if I'm going to run into any problems with code structured like this. I have an @Observable class Foo that I want to use to control a Toggle inside a subview. The main App instantiates Foo and passes it into the environment for all subviews. If I access it as an @Environment property in the subview and try to do isOn: $foo.bar in the toggle, the error says "Cannot find $foo in scope". Is this because Environment properties are not two-way bindable? So here's my solution:
@Observable
class Foo {
    var bar: Bool
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
   @State var foo = Foo()

   var body: some View {
       ContentView()
           .environment(foo)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(Foo.self) private var foo

    var body: some View {
        Subview(foo: foo)
    }
}

struct Subview: View {
    @State var foo: Foo

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $foo.bar)
    }
}

It seems wrong to be unable to use @Environment properties for two-way bindings, but OK to pass them as state parameters to subviews which do exactly that. Is this solution going to cause bugs?

State should always be private, State is a source of truth, use Bindable to get bindings

State is only for values or structs

I don't think that is still true @malhal https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

It is true. The docs are out of date. There was one beta where state was changed to have auto closure thunk like stateobject but they changed it back and didn't update the docs
